# IVR input through voice without lex

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

i just want to know can we take input in IVR through voice without lex in amazon connect. If yes So, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Connect does not have Speech-To-Text capability on its own. It uses Lex for that.

So without using Lex, Connect can only operate like the old automatic phone operators using the DTMF (number keypad input).